# Is triplex wire legal for running a sub-panel?

Tags: wiring

When I bought the house it had a section of triplex wire that ran to a 50A breaker with the remainder coiled in rafter space of the covered porch. (When I discovered this, the triplex was hot.  That breaker is currently off and taped off.)  I would like to put a sub panel in the garage, which shares the covered porch.

Can I use the existing triplex for this?

Edit:  Present wire consists of 1 aluminum uninsulated, and 2 insulated wires.  The insulated ones are marked CANADA I Wire 4 Aluminum 6 and some illegible stuff in orange.  I need to uncoil it to find a better copy.

My suspicion is "no"

Thinking about this, it's definitely a 'no'  The whole point is to get 220 for a new table saw.  Which means 4 conductor wire, not 3.

Failing that, what is the best way to use the existing triplex wire to get acceptable code wire from the rafter space to the main panel without taking apart the wall?

- Cut the triplex off short of it's entry point into the house wall.
- Tape/solder conventional wire to the triplex.
- Shut off the power, disconnect the triplex from the breaker, undo the strain relieve, and try to worry it all back into the main panel box..

OR

Do the same operation but do the feed from the main panel end.

OR

Use the triplex to get someing more flexible through the route (fish tape? Rope?) and attach the new wire to it?

Comment: Does he triplex have a white neutral or a bare ground?

Comment: Depends on wire size and other factors. Is there any label printed on the cable sheath?

Comment: Also is this wire #4 or above?  How do you feel about having 120V-only in the garage subpanel?

Comment: Can you post the labeling information written on the cable sheath? Also, does the triplex consist of three insulated wires, or two insulated wires and a bare wire?

Comment: Edited to include part of wire label.

Comment: Note that if you ONLY need 240V and not any 120V, you can do a 240V-only panel with a three wire supply -- in that case, you have hot/hot/ground and no neutrals.

Comment: Nah.  Too many of my toys are 110.  But I get your point....

Comment: @NateStrickland The problem with 3-wire 240-only H-H-G to a subpanel is *sooner or later, The Next Guy decides to add a 120V circuit*.  He slaps neutral and ground on the bar with all the wires going to it, and calls it hunky dory.  Because that's how it's done in the main panel, and he doesn't see a separate neutral bar, so this must be grandfathered right?

Comment: @Harper, true.  IMO a 240V-only panel should be clearly labeled as such, to avoid next-guy problems.  I don't think code requires that, but it's definitely good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Triplex is designed and approved to be suspended on free air across open space.  You need an altogether different type of wire.

Comment: There are several styles of "triplex" -- overhead distribution, URD, and "mobile home feeder" (which is really a quadplex cable)